# How can I resolve a compiler error in Clion on MacOS when using the gtkmm4 library?

Tags: c, macos, clion

Can someone help me figure out why I am getting this error in my compiler in Clion?

This is my CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(gtk)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GTK4 REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET gtkmm-4.0)

add_executable(gtk src/main.cpp src/gui.cpp src/gui.hpp src/plot/plotter.cpp src/plot/plotter.hpp src/plot/plotter.cpp src/plot/plotter.hpp src/plot/plottercoords.cpp src/plot/plotterevents.cpp src/plot/plotterlabels.cpp src/plot/plotteroptions.cpp src/plot/plotterseries.cpp src/plot/plotterthemes.cpp src/plot/plotterwidgets.cpp)
target_link_libraries(gtk PRIVATE ${GTK4_LIBRARIES})

target_compile_definitions(gtk PRIVATE ${GTK4_CFLAGS_OTHER})

target_include_directories(gtk PRIVATE ${GTK4_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_directories(gtk PRIVATE ${GTK4_LIBRARY_DIRS})
```

Below is my console output when I 'reset cache and reload project' from the dropdown menu.

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/make -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" -S /Users/zenith412/Desktop/Saturn/trexs/gtk -B /Users/zenith412/Desktop/Saturn/trexs/gtk/cmake-build-debug
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/zenith412/Desktop/Saturn/trexs/gtk/cmake-build-debug

Cannot get compiler information:
    Compiler exited with error code 1: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++ -xc++ -D-mfpmath=sse -D-msse -D-msse2 -g -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk -std=gnu++2b -fpch-preprocess -v -dD -E
    Homebrew clang version 16.0.4
    Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.5.0
    Thread model: posix
    InstalledDir: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin
     (in-process)
     "/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/16.0.4/bin/clang-16" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx13.0.0 -Wundef-prefix=TARGET_OS_ -Werror=undef-prefix -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -E -disable-free -clear-ast-before-backend -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name compiler-file18281748440535425928 -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mframe-pointer=all -ffp-contract=on -fno-rounding-math -funwind-tables=2 -target-sdk-version=13.3 -fcompatibility-qualified-id-block-type-checking -fvisibility-inlines-hidden-static-local-var -target-cpu penryn -tune-cpu generic -debug-info-kind=standalone -dwarf-version=4 -debugger-tuning=lldb -target-linker-version 857.1 -v -fcoverage-compilation-dir=/Users/shivpatel/Desktop/Saturn/trexs/gtk/cmake-build-debug -resource-dir /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/16.0.4/lib/clang/16 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk -D -mfpmath=sse -D -msse -D -msse2 -D ___CIDR_DEFINITIONS_END -internal-isystem /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1 -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/16.0.4/lib/clang/16/include -internal-externc-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include -std=gnu++2b -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir=/Users/zenith412/Desktop/Saturn/trexs/gtk/cmake-build-debug -ferror-limit 19 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fencode-extended-block-signature -fregister-global-dtors-with-atexit -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -dD -D__GCC_HAVE_DWARF2_CFI_ASM=1 -o - -x c++ /private/var/folders/dp/14_5b22171nc4l3vwtn3dyv40000gn/T/compiler-file18281748440535425928
    clang -cc1 version 16.0.4 based upon LLVM 16.0.4 default target x86_64-apple-darwin22.5.0
    #include "..." search starts here:
    #include <...> search starts here:
     /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1
     /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/local/include
     /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/16.0.4/lib/clang/16/include
     /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/include
     /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
     /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
    End of search list.
    In file included from <built-in>:461:
    <command line>:1:9: error: macro name must be an identifier
    #define -mfpmath sse
            ^
    <command line>:2:9: error: macro name must be an identifier
    #define -msse 1
            ^
    <command line>:3:9: error: macro name must be an identifier
    #define -msse2 1
            ^
    3 errors generated.
    
    

[Failed to reload]
```

I have a feeling the issue comes from the following but I am not sure how to fix it.

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk -D -mfpmath=sse -D -msse -D -msse2 -D ___CIDR_DEFINITIONS_END -internal-isystem /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/../include/c++/v1 -internal-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/16.0.4/lib/clang/16/include -internal-externc-isystem
```

I reinstalled Xcode, clang, llvm, updated my homebrew as well as my MacOS operating system to the most recent release. Nothing causes this error to go away. I ran the `conda deactivate`  command in my terminal too.

the main thing im trying to do is to use the `gtkmm4` libraries in my code.

Answer (score 1):

${GTK4_CFLAGS_OTHER} are not compile definitions, but rather just compiler options.

so instead of:

```
target_compile_definitions(gtk PRIVATE ${GTK4_CFLAGS_OTHER})
```

use:

```
target_compile_options(gtk PRIVATE ${GTK4_CFLAGS_OTHER})
```